# std::chrono::system_clock and duration<double>

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++-chrono

I can measure time using:

```
t1 = system_clock::now();
...
t2 = system_clock::now();

duration<double> d = t2 - t1;
```

That compiles fine, but how do I do the reverse? I want to move a time point using duration?

example (does not compile):

```
system_clock::time_point tp1 = system_clock::now();
system_clock::time_point tp2 = tp1 + duration<double>(1.0);
```

The `system_clock::time_point` '+' operator does not seem to accept `duration<double>`.

How can I move a time point by a duration specified using time in seconds (floating point value)? I need to use `system_clock` because it can convert to `time_t`.

Comment: Convert the duration to a integer version (e.g. std::chrono::microseconds)?

Comment: @MikeMB Can you please post an example of how to do that? Do I have to convert the float value to the duration using 'duration::period'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I went with the following (seeing as VS2012 might have a bug in 'duration_cast'). To add a time duration specified in seconds (using floating point) to a system_clock time point:

```
const double SECS_TO_SYSTEM_TICKS = (double)system_clock::period::den / (double)system_clock::period::num;
system_clock::time_point tp1 = system_clock::now()
double dTimeS = 1.0;

...

system_clock::duration d((system_clock::rep)(floor(dTimeS) * SECS_TO_SYSTEM_TICKS));
time_t t = system_clock::to_time_t(t1 + d);
```

I use 'floor(dTimeS)' just because in my implementation I do not want the fractional seconds to be rounded up to seconds.

The following should also work on a newer compiler (according to José's answer):

```
system_clock::duration d = duration_cast<system_clock::duration>(duration<double>(floor(dTimeS)));
time_t t = system_clock::to_time_t(t1 + d);
```

This also worked for me:

```
auto secs = seconds((seconds::rep)floor(dTimeS));
auto system_ticks = duration_cast<system_clock::duration>(secs);
time_t t = system_clock::to_time_t(t1 + system_ticks);
```

NOTE: The rounding behaviour (ticks to seconds) of 'to_time_t' is unspecified and if I need the fractional seconds I extract it separately.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

```
system_clock::time_point tp1 = system_clock::now(); 
system_clock::time_point tp2 = tp1 + duration_cast<system_clock::duration>(duration<double>(1.5));
cout << duration_cast<milliseconds>(tp2 - tp1).count();
```

Output: difference is 1500ms

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/Pq5Q0U)

Comment: Note that `microseconds` is not guaranteed to be the correct type for `system_clock`. You should cast to `system_clock::duration`

Comment: My compiler does not accept 'std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::system_clock::duration>(std::chrono::duration<double>(1.5))'. error: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from '_CR' to 'std::chrono::system_clock::duration'.

I'm using VS2012

Comment: This is because there's a bug in VS 2012.

Comment: Any suggested workarounds for the bug? Unfortunately, at least for now, I'm stuck in the past with VS2012.